# Gitlens causing line break before code block

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I recently started using the [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) vscode extension, and it offers alot of great features.  However, it seems to be creating an empty line above code blocks sometimes, like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's this empty space between line 11 and 12, just to tell me about the git blame.  I played with the settings and I can't seem to get rid of it, and its driving me nuts.  Anyone know how to remove git blame annotation that causes the line space?

Comment: change setting `"gitlens.codeLens.enabled": false`

Comment: That didn't do it

Answer (score 15):

If anyone else has this problem, I solved it by searching for 'block' in vscode settings, fiding the gitlens section, and disabling these:

- `Gitlens › Code Lens › Authors: Enabled`
- `Gitlens › Code Lens › Recent Change: Enabled`

Comment: I encountered the same problem, too. Thanks for your help.